# Ask in runtime permission for push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, request, android-permissions

I'm workin an app and when the app start, i need to ask at the user if he want to receive push notification. I know that push notification aren't a dangerous permission but i need to show the popup with the possibility to chose. 
This is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
```

And this is the runtime method that should show the popup

```
public void receiveNotification(View v) {

    boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    if (hasPermission) {

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(Tag, "Token"+token);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(Tag, "Token"+token);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else  {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}
```

Someone has idea how can i show this popup? It's importat :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Create your own `DialogFragment` and `AlertDialog`. You cannot invent new runtime permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have an example? With my AlertDialog, how can i communicate this chose at the andoird system?

Comment: "You have an example?" -- you might consider looking at [the `DialogFragment` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). "how can i communicate this chose at the andoird system?" -- I do not know what you are asking, sorry.